# joining table returns extra rows

Tags: oracle, join

i am stuck in a oracle query

what i am doing is  i am joining two tables on there cityid .

whats happening is when i query the first table its returning 486 rows but when i join them no matter which join and join it on the cityid it 
returns 570 rows please advice how can i get only the 486 records

the query is as follows

```
select c.year,c.amount,c.product,g.state 
from Accounts c 
join Address g 
  on g.cityid=c.cityid
order by c.year,c.product;
```

regards

Comment: This is the HQL query, can you give us the mapping used? From the HQL query the join is done with the cityid not the cust id.

Comment: thx theewook i wrote it wrong

Comment: Why would a table named "Address" be serving as a lookup-state-by-city table? It seems the `Address` table is likely to multiple records per city and probably isn't the table you should be using.

Answer (score 2):

That's perfectly possible.

If you have multiple addresses for a given account, or multiple accounts for a given address, you may wind up with more rows than just what's in the address or account table.

Consider:

```
Account
id | ... | cityid
 4 | ... | 12
 5 | ... | 12
 6 | ... | 13
 7 | ... | 14

Address
id | ... | cityid
 2 | ... | 12
 3 | ... | 13
 4 | ... | 14
```

With your join you get:

```
Account           Address
id | ... | cityid | id | ... | cityid
 4 | ... | 12     |  2 | ... | 12
 5 | ... | 12     |  2 | ... | 12
 6 | ... | 13     |  3 | ... | 13
 7 | ... | 14     |  4 | ... | 14
```

So, you see there are 4 records returned, even though there are 3 records in Address, with record Address.2 being repeated.

This could go the other way if the foreign key relationships were reversed.

And this is actually the core feature of relational databases, that data entered with foreign key relationships maintained do not need to repeat data entry.

You can limit the rows by selecting only the first (lowest id) value to join on .. this usually involves creating a temporary table, which is an exercise I will leave to an oracle expert, because I think that Sybase's syntax for that is different (and required to be done within a stored procedure, yick).

I find myself wondering if there might be a slightly different interpretation of the schema outside what you've described that might be more likely to resolve your issue.

Comment: hi thanks for the rply in my case the cityids are foreign key and foreign keys join will return duplicate values so how do i get the unique values

Comment: You can add distinct(Account.cityid) to the select, but this may not be what you are hoping for.  I really do think there's a missing piece in understanding the full schema.

Comment: see i have two views from the first view i want the product its amountand count in this view cityid is used which is a foreign key and i am joining cityid of the second view to get that state again city id is foreign key and a state contains many city. when iam only querying the first view it rerurns 486 records and if i query it by joining the second view it retutns 540 records out of which 7 cintained null citis tahat i filtered using where clause what might i be doing wrong

Comment: Well, views are evil, so try not to use them.  They lead to surprising results.  http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffm/archive/2008/02/12/Why-Views-are-evil.aspx

I've never seen a join return null left or right records unless it's an outer join.  I suppose you could add a where clause to remove nulls:

... where Address.cityid is not null

Comment: hi paul thanks for your help i manged to rectify it each city had branch and those branch were mapping to the same city id thus resulting in extra records .